# Arabic Font not applied in crystal report viewer when display in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I create asp.net and Crystal Reports website

Arabic font not applied in crystal report viewer when but when export to PDF it appears correctly. Ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on the required fields - Format Object - Paragraph : Reading Order Right to left

But viewer is always a bit wonky in my experience as it never presents the same info as an export.

Comment: thanks to answer my question , yes the viewer never presents the same but when export to PDF it coming good